# SLD - at the end of the parameter in label the letter ‘Z’ was added

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have some basic SLD style for polygon with label. The date parameter is displayed in the label, and that's ok. But at the end of the date the letter ‘Z’ was added, why is this happening?

SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 <NamedLayer>
<Name></Name>
<UserStyle>
  <Title></Title>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>test</Name>
      <Title>test</Title>
      <Abstract>test</Abstract>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
            <ogc:Literal>0.01</ogc:Literal>
          </CssParameter>
        </Fill>

      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>

    <Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>5001</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <TextSymbolizer>
        
        <Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>date</ogc:PropertyName>
        </Label>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Dialog.bold</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-weight">Bold</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
        </Font>
        <LabelPlacement>
          <PointPlacement>
            <AnchorPoint>
              <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
              <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
            </AnchorPoint>
            <Displacement>
              <DisplacementX>0</DisplacementX>
              <DisplacementY>65</DisplacementY>
            </Displacement>
          </PointPlacement>

        </LabelPlacement>

        <Halo>
          <Radius>
            <ogc:Literal>1.2</ogc:Literal>
          </Radius>
          <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#666666</CssParameter>
          </Fill>
        </Halo>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </TextSymbolizer>
    </Rule>

  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

[image]

Data base:
patameter date: data type date
[image]

Comment: I have seen also in some other places that GeoServer adds Z to dates. It means that the  date is in UTC time zone.

Comment: @user30184 can I remove/hide that Z?

Comment: There is a date format function you can use to hide the timezone, but it is good practice to include the timezone when displaying times and dates - see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#parsing-and-formatting-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else has the same problem, here is how I solved the problem:

The 'date' parameter in the table in the database has the date format, the standard interpretation of the timestamp on the GeoServer is the format **yyyy-MM-ddThh: mm: ss.SSSZ**. So I find solution to use the **dateformat style function**.

```
<Label>
    <ogc:Function name="dateFormat">
         <ogc:Literal>yyyy-MM-dd</ogc:Literal>
         <ogc:PropertyName>datum</ogc:PropertyName>
    </ogc:Function>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 3):

The "Z" indicates that GeoServer assumes that the date is in UTC timezone. If that is the case everything is OK and you can probably just remove it by using the format function as suggested by Ian.

If the dates in the database are in a local timezone and you really need to take the timezone into consideration you can configure GeoServer to assume that dates are local by adding

`-Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true`

to the java startup arguments. Exactly how you do that depends on how you start GeoServer.